# Using SSH to run custom scripts on a Unix server in C#

Tags: c#, unix, .net-4.0, ssh

Hey all, Ive been using a [new SHH library](http://sshnet.codeplex.com/) to send commands to a unix server and its been working great for me.  It sends normal commands just fine and recives the proper responses.  However, I seem to be running into an issue when I try to use it to run a custom script (not a shell script, but a file that contains another command and has arguments)

Ive tried several ways to get this to work.

On the unix server itself the following commands work perfectly and do what they are intended:

- cd script; script.oi someArg someArg - WORKS
- csh -c "cd script; script.oi someArg someArg" - ALSO WORKS
- cd /users/bin/script; script.oi someArg1 someArg 2 - WORKS
- csh -c "cd /users/bin/script; script.oi someArg1 someArg 2" - WORKS
- /users/bin/script/script.oi someArg1 someArg2 - WORKS

However, in the code I have tried the following:

```
string command = string.Format("csh -c \"cd script; script.oi {0} {1}\"", arg1, arg2); - DOES NOT WORK
string command = string.Format("cd script; script.oi {0} {1}", arg1, arg2); - DOES NOT WORK
string command = string.Format("cd /users/bin/script; script.oi {0} {1}", arg1, arg2); - DOES NOT WORK 
string command = string.Format("csh -c \"cd /users/bin/script; script.oi {0} {1}\"", arg1, arg2); - DOES NOT WORK 
string command = string.Format("/users/bin/script/script.oi {0} {1}", arg1, arg2); - DOES NOT WORK
```

So to me it seems like something else is going on.  I did try the following:

```
string command = string.Format("csh -c \"ls\"", arg1, arg2);` - WORKS
string command = string.Format("ls", arg1, arg2);` - WORKS
```

It looks like it has to do with the fact that Im trying to run a custom script, or maybe some silly setting I've forgotten.  Let me know if you need anymore details.

**EDIT:** By DOES NOT WORK, I mean that the result that is returned to the C# is supposed to say some stuff, but the result is blank.  Additionaly, the script sends a TIBCO Rendevous message which eventually adds an entry to a DB, which is not showing up.  When I say WORKS, I mean that the entry is showing up in the DB.

Comment: What does _DOES NOT WORK_ mean? Do you get an error message? Do you get an invalid result? I was just wondering if you maybe use arguments with spaces or invalid chars in case of the custom scripts? And: Which mode does script.oi have? 777? 755?

Comment: The results (output of the command) is blank, and the script is supposed to add an entry to a DB via sending a TIBCO Rendevous message, and that entry is never added.  Not sure what you mean by the scripts mode.... all it is is the TIBCO Rendevous message with the arguments

Comment: Just the rights of the filesystem for `script.oi`. What does `ls -al /users/bin/script/script.oi` output?

Comment: Im a huge unix noob but when I ran that command I think what you're looking for is the beginning of it `-rwx--x--x`

Comment: Also, what are your values for `arg1` and `arg2`? And which user do you use to login?

Comment: If you provide the full line you will tell me to which user and group the script belongs to.

Comment: `-rwx--x--x 1 smdev_m users 156 Nov 5 10:24 script.oi` The args are just strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I figured it out.  Turns out the script was running a command that is known to the unix server via being added to the unix eviroment variables.  When just using the standard way to send commands in SSH.NET, the enviroment variables are not imported (which is why you are able to send normal commands like ls, grep, cat, ect, but not this one).

The fix was to use the libraries SSH shell functionality because it *does* import the enviroment variables, therefore it knows what that command in the script is and is able to run it.  For those using this great library (which is still be activily developed, always a plus) I have included below example SSH.NET Shell code.

```
PasswordConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new PasswordConnectionInfo("some IP", "user", "pass");

try
{
    using (var client = new SshClient(connectionInfo))
    {
        client.Connect();
        var input = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command));
        var shell = client.CreateShell(input, Console.Out, Console.Out, "xterm", 80, 24, 800, 600, "");
        shell.Stopped += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nDisconnected...");
        };
        shell.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        shell.Stop();
        client.Disconnect();
    }   
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Exception stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the user being logged on using the ssh client have execute privileges on the called executable?

Comment: The user that is logged in on the actual Unix server when running those executables/scripts works is the same user/password I used for the login info on the SSH connection

Comment: Attempt running them with a different shell? Bash for instance?

Comment: Also it could be worth returning pwd which should let you see what directory your execution is going to happen in...

Comment: Thanks for the link; checked the directory execution and it seems right

Comment: Can you add some kind of logging to the script?

Comment: Actually better still, pipe the output of the command like this: script.oi a2test003 hed > output.txt

Comment: Ill have to see if its cosher for me to create files on the server first so I wont be able to try this till tomorrow but its a fanatstic idea

Comment: I tried `cd script; script.oi A2TEST003 HED > output.txt` on the unix server and the DB entry was successfully added, but the text file was not created.

Comment: try running "touch output.txt" first. that should create the file.

Comment: Okay, that seemed to put what usally appears in the console after I run the script in that output file, but the entry did not appear in the DB.  I think that its good to note too that all the "script" does is run a command (Like I said before, tibco rendvous message command), so I tried running the command in the script from the code (bypassing any script issues) and the command still failed to have a result.

Comment: It may be worth piping that output last?

Comment: Piping the output of the command by itself, outside of the script?

Comment: It is also worth piping stderr like so:  script.oi someArg someArg >output.txt 2>&1

Comment: That results in `Ambiguous output redirect.`

Comment: If you could re-try with:  1> output.txt 2>&1

Comment: I tried `script.oi A2TEST003 HED 1> output.txt 2>&1` and got `Ambiguous output redirect.`

Answer (score 0):

As the script should be executable by everyone there should be something wrong with the arguments. Get the generated command-String and try to execute it by yourself on a SSH-session (with something like PuTTY). If possible provide us the generated command. I assume there might be chars in it which need proper escaping.

Comment: Even if the arguments are just strings it is possible that whitespaces and chars like `<` and `>` make problems.

Comment: Ah I see, well the current are something like `script.oi A2TEST003 HED`

Comment: Okay, that should not be a problem. Can you login with a SSH client like PuTTY ( http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/ ) and execute the command by typing it?

Comment: Okay connected via PuTTY with the same info and ran `cd script; script.oi A2TEST003 HED` and the entry did show up in the DB